# Send mails from redmine container

Tags: docker

These 2 commands install redmine using docker.

```
docker run --name myred1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=india -e MYSQL_DATABASE=redmine -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d  -v /storage/mysql/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:5.6


docker run --name dbt -p 3000:3000 -v /my/own/datadir:/usr/src/redmine/files --link myred1:mysql -d redmine
```

But I am not able to send mails from within redmine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure email delivery in Redmine, you have to edit `configuration.yml` :

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
      port: '587'
      domain: "smtp.gmail.com" 
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "sender@gmail.com" 
      password: "senderpassword"
```

Mount the file to your `redmine` image with :

```
-v /somedir/config/configuration.yml:/usr/src/redmine/config/configuration.yml
```